# VBA (Excel) course homework

Tags: excel, vba

My name is Johnny and I just started a course in VBA in my school. I've gotten an assignment which we should discuss upcoming Friday again.
TBH I'm new to programming and struggling a bit, so hope you can help me with this assignment.

Assignment Step 1 - 10 I've already completed:

***some examples of the tasks:***

1. Create "WorksheetA"
2. Create "WorksheetB"
3. Create Dropdown list on "Worksheet A" containing 3 options ("Dog", "Cat", "Fish")
4. Create Table for size on "WorksheetA"
5. Create Formula on Worksheet A in cell K8 (=VLOOKUP(K5,A2:C11,2,)
6. Create a button on "WorksheetA"
7. Protect "WorksheetA"

So far this was easy, now comes the tricky part where I'm struggling:

Create and assign a VBA macro to the button on "WorksheetA"
The Macro should:

1. Copy the value from the formula created in cell K8
2. Condition 1: If the dropdown says "Dogs", paste the value on "WorksheetB" cell B1
3. Condition 2: If the dropdown says "Cats", paste the value on "WorksheetB" cell B2
4. Condition 3: If the dropdown says "Fish", paste the value on "WorksheetB" cell B3

Here is what I have written in the VBA editor so far:

```
@ChristoferWeber Ok now have this:


Sub ButtonA()
'
' ButtonA Macro
'

' Unprotect sheet

Dim cell As Range

Set cell = Worksheets("WorksheetA").Range("K15")

Worksheets("WorksheetA").Unprotect

If InStr(cell.Value, "Dog") Then Worksheets("WorksheetA").Range("K8").Copy Worksheets("WorksheetB").Range("B1")
        ElseIf InStr(cell.Value, "Cat") Then Worksheets("WorksheetA").Range("K8").Copy Worksheets("WorksheetB").Range("B2").Value
        ElseIf InStr(cell.Value, "Fish") Then Worksheets("WorksheetA").Range("K8").Copy Worksheets("WorksheetB").Range("B3").Value

End If

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Worksheets("WorksheetA").Protect
    
End Sub
```

When I try to execute the code by clicking the button, the whole thing throws up.

I've found most of the above by Googling and putting together some of the code snippet's I've found.

What I think is wrong:

```
InStr(cell.Value, "Cat")
```

I've not defined where this cell is.

Hope you can help me out! Thanks a lot for your time.

**Two images:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9r6nH.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CU9Za.jpg

Comment: `cell` ---> `Worksheets("WorksheetA").Range("K8")`?

Comment: `Worksheets("WorksheetA").Range("K8").Copy Worksheets("WorksheetB").Range("B1")` and similar should be on a new line. Note that `Copy` doesn't copy the *value* though.

Comment: I think your ElseIf and EndIf syntax is wrong. Look that up in documentation.

Comment: @BigBen Sorry, I do not understand your first comment.. How to copy the value then?

Comment: @JSmart523 Could very well be, as I used hwta I found online. I'm now looking through some tutorials.

Comment: @snenson It is not working, it throws error.

Comment: you get the value of a cell with cell(rownumber, columnnumber).value or range("B2").value

Comment: `Worksheets("WorksheetB").Range("B1").Value = Worksheets("WorksheetA").Range("K8").Value`.

Comment: Which cell contains the "cat" "dog" or "fish"?

Comment: `Dim cell As Range`     
                    
                  
 And then              
                 
`set cell = Worksheets("WorksheetA").Range("A1")` (Whatever cell contains the drop down)

Comment: @snenson call K15 contains the dropdown with Dog / Cat / Fish

Comment: Ok but where does the dropdown get its values from and where does it print the index/number?

Comment: @snenson It gives me compiler error: "Else without If"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you dont need the i variable like in my first solution. This would work with an Combo Box.
Now you need something like that:

```
Sub ButtonA()
Dim pet As String

Worksheets("WorksheetA").Unprotect

pet = Worksheets("WorksheetA").Range("K15").Value
Formula = Worksheets("WorksheetA").Range("K8").Value
If pet = "dog" Then
    Worksheets("WorksheetB").Range("B1").Value = Formula
ElseIf pet = "Cat" Then
    Worksheets("WorksheetB").Range("B2").Value = Formula
ElseIf pet = "Fish" Then
    Worksheets("WorksheetB").Range("B3").Value = Formula
End If

    
Worksheets("WorksheetA").Protect
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the dropdown index, this is the value of the cell where you linked the dropdown to. In your case it should be a number between 1 and 3.

In my example it would be `WorksheetA.Range("A3").value`, assign it to variable i like `i=WorksheetA.Range("A3").value`
The values which are listed in the dropdown are in `WorksheetA.Range("D3:D5")`
To get the right pet for the index take the first cell of the listed pets (in my case D3) and move from there. `pet=Worksheet.Cells(3+i-1,4).Value`

Your macro for my example would look like that:

```
Sub ButtonA()
Dim i As Integer
Dim pet As String

Worksheets("WorksheetA").Unprotect

i = Worksheets("WorksheetA").Range("A3").Value
pet = Worksheets("WorksheetA").Cells(3 + i - 1, 4).Value
Formula = Worksheets("WorksheetA").Range("K8").Value
If pet = "dog" Then 
    Worksheets("WorksheetB").Range("B1").Value = Formula
ElseIf pet = "Cat" Then 
    Worksheets("WorksheetB").Range("B2").Value = Formula
ElseIf pet = "Fish" Then 
    Worksheets("WorksheetB").Range("B3").Value = Formula
End If

    
Worksheets("WorksheetA").Protect
    
End Sub
```

I hope that helps to complete the task.

Comment: Thanks! I will study it and give it a go. Brb!

Comment: It gives me compiler error: "Else without If"

Comment: Yeah sorry i forgot to add new lines, now it should work.

Comment: Thanks, now I know how to add these things on new lines!

Unfortunately the code does not work. It does not give an error message when I click the button, but it also does not paste anything on WorksheetB

Comment: The reason for that could be, that you didnt change the range. Where does your dropdown get his values from?

Comment: I created a table with that data here:

Dog @ AG7
Cat @ AG8
Fish @ AG9

This is what I did to try and change the range:

i = Worksheets("Calculator").Range("AG7").Value
name = Worksheets("Calculator").Cells(7 + i - 1, 33).Value

Comment: The last is right but the i is false. If you change your selection in the drop down, where does the number change? There has to be a cell where the value is 1 if you selected dog, 2 in case of cat and 3 in case of fish.

Comment: Does it work now or do you need further help?

Comment: No I'm just trying different things, but it is not working still.
I do not understand what you mean exactly..

If Dog is selected in the drop down on WorksheetA, where should there be a value 1? or value 2 when Cat is selected?

Comment: If you right-click on your dropdown and go to Format Control->Cell link, select a cell and there will be the 1,2 or 3

Comment: When I right-click my drop down, there are many options, but not Format Control, nor Cell link.
There is "Format cell" however.

Comment: Could you upload a screenshot of what the spreadsheet and the dropdown looks like?